# Calculate fraction of complete/not missing values of variables in a data frame for output in a long format

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I've got a data frame (`df1`) with four variables, `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`.

I'd like to get the completeness (`!is.na(x)`) for each variable in the data frame. I'd like the output to be in long format (`df2`).

The problem's that I can't get the `nrow()` part of my code to work (therefore I don't know if it works overall). Or is there a dplyr+tidyr way of doing it?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Starting point (`df1`):

```
df1 <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,NA),b=c(1,2,NA,NA),c=c(1,2,3,4),d=c(NA,NA,NA,NA),stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
```

Current code:

```
sapply(df1, function(x) sum(!is.na(df1$x)) / nrow(df1$x))
```

Desired outcome (`df2`):

```
df2 <- data.frame(nameofvar=c("a","b","c","d"),completeness=c(75,50,100,0))
```

Comment: Easiest solution imo: `stack(colMeans(!is.na(df1))*100)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you wanted the answer to be in the *long format*, here’s how:

```
df2 = df1 %>%
    gather(NameOfVar, Value) %>%
    group_by(NameOfVar) %>%
    summarize(Completeness = mean(! is.na(Value)) * 100)
```

As for why your (base R) code isn’t working:

When `sapply`ing over a data.frame, the argument to your function (`x`) is the column data itself. So instead of having `df1$x`<sup>1</sup> you need to just use `x`, and instead of `nrow` you now need to use `length`, since each column `x` is a *vector*.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> In addition, `$`-subsetting with a variable never works,
 so even if `x` was a column name/index, `df1$x` wouldn’t work anyway. You’d have to use `df1[[x]]` instead.</sub>

Comment: I'd just use `mean(!is.na(Value))`

Comment: @docendodiscimus Yes, of course. Duh. (Though I have to say, it makes the code much less clear — that said, this is how I’d also usually write the code).

Answer (score 1):

try `purrr` package part of `tidyverse`.

```
df1 %>% 
  map_df(~ sum(!is.na(.)) / length(.) * 100)
```

Answer (score 1):

with `data.table`

```
dt1 <- as.data.table(df1)
dt1[, sapply(.SD, function(x) {sum(!is.na(x)) / .N}), .SD = names(dt1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Or very simply with base R:

```
colSums(!is.na(df1))/ ncol(df1) * 100
```

Comment: It should be `colSums(!is.na(df1))/ ncol(df1) * 100`

Comment: Even simpler: `colMeans(!is.na(df))`

Comment: Yes, I agree with you both.

Answer (score 0):

Using only `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,NA),
                  b=c(1,2,NA,NA),
                  c=c(1,2,3,4),
                  d=c(NA,NA,NA,NA),
                  stringsAsFactors = TRUE)

# get percentage of non NA values
df1 %>% summarise_all(function(x) mean(! is.na(x)))

#      a   b c d
# 1 0.75 0.5 1 0
```